what is wrong with my intuition for the sum of the reciprocals of primes?
So we know that since two is prime, half of all natural numbers are divisible by 2, a third of all natural numbers are divisible by 3, and a fifth of all natural numbers are divisible by 5. So if we take half of all natural  numbers, a thrid of all natural numbers, and fifth of all  natural numbers, and so on till the 1/n of all natural numbers where n is prime if we take the limit as n goes to infinity than we should get the set of all natural numbers.
So would it make sense to say that 1/2+1/3+1/5+... = 1 since this gives us all natural  numbers?
what is wrong with my intuition here. Without doing any calculation why can we see this reasoning is wrong? Does this kind of reasoning to contrsuct the set of natural numbers have any value?

Did you account for those natural numbers that are divisible by both $2$ and $3$?

oh I see oh it overcounts. that makes sense. I wonder if there is any way to do this to get 1, like take half of the numbers than take only (1/2)(1/3) to only count the ones divisible by 3 and then take (1/2)(1/3)*(1/5)  and so on. Would that converge?

A bit of a side question, but why do you make 2 being prime a condition of "half of all natural numbers are divisible by 2"? For example, 4 is nonprime, but 1/4 of all natural numbers are still divisible by 4. Or in general, regardless of whether $n$ is prime, $1/n$ of all natural numbers are divisible by $n$. So why "since two is prime"?

First, $\dfrac{1}{2}+\dfrac{1}{3}+\dfrac{1}{5} = \dfrac{31}{30} > 1$, so clearly $\dfrac{1}{2}+\dfrac{1}{3}+\dfrac{1}{5}+\cdots$ will either add up to something bigger than $1$ or diverge. (In fact, it diverges. See this link https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divergence_of_the_sum_of_the_reciprocals_of_the_primes)
Also, the underlying flaw in your reasoning is that there are numbers which are divisible by multiple primes. For large $N$, the set $\{1,2,\ldots,N\}$ contains roughly $\dfrac{1}{2}N$ numbers which are divisible by $2$, roughly $\dfrac{1}{3}N$ numbers which are divisible by $3$, and roughly $\dfrac{1}{6}N$ numbers which are divisible by both $2$ and $3$. So that set has roughly $\dfrac{1}{2}N+\dfrac{1}{3}N-\dfrac{1}{6}N = \dfrac{2}{3}N$ numbers which are divisible by either $2$ or $3$, not $\dfrac{1}{2}N+\dfrac{1}{3}N = \dfrac{5}{6}N$. So you can't simply add the fractions of numbers which are divisible by each prime and get $1$.
In general, when you are trying to count the union of many sets, something called the Principle of Inclusion-Exclusion
(sometimes abbreviated PIE) applies. For two sets, we have $$|A_1 \cup A_2| = |A_1| + |A_2| - |A_1 \cap A_2|.$$ For three sets, we have $$|A_1 \cup A_2 \cup A_3| = |A_1|+|A_2|+|A_3|-|A_1 \cap A_2|-|A_2 \cap A_3|-|A_3 \cap A_1|+|A_1 \cap A_2 \cap A_3|.$$ And this can be generalized to more sets.

Yes I understand that but using the same reasoning would this series converge?
1/2+(1/2)(1/3)+(1/2)(1/3)(1/5)+(1/2)(1/3)(1/5)(1/7)+...+ and would it be equal to 1.
this seems like it removes the overcount of numbers divisible by multiple primes.

@MonsterRamen That series does converge, but to some random constant between $0.70$ and $0.71$. I think you were thinking of $\frac12+(1-\frac12)\frac13+(1-\frac12)(1-\frac13)\frac15+(1-\frac12)(1-\frac13)(1-\frac15)\frac17+\cdots$. That series does converge to $1$, but it's not a special propertiy of the primes $(2,3,5,7,\ldots)$—they could be replaced by any sequence of real numbers bounded below by $2$ (say) and the series would still converge to $1$.

@GregMartin could you explain that formula a bit more. why is it that (1-1/2)(1/3) gives the fraction of  numbers divisible by 3 and not 2 and why does (1-1/2)(1-1/3)1/5 give the fraction of numbers divisble by 5 and not 3, or 2?

@MonsterRamen Do you know why $(1-2/6)$ gives the fraction of dice rolls (on a standard $6$-sided die) not equal to 4 or 5? And do you know $(2/6)(1/2)$ is the probability that when you roll a die and flip a coin, you both get a 2 or a 3 on the die and get tails? If so, the reasons are the same here. If not, you will need to study "complements" and "independent events" in probability (e.g. on Khan Academy) and then come back to this question.

@MonsterRamen If you correctly apply inclusion-exclusion you will get $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \mu(n)/n = 0$, where $\mu$ is the Möbius function. This result is correct but a rigorous proof is not easy.
